# Printing a value once in processing

Tags: processing

I would like to make it so that when a key is pressed that I get only a single printing of my variable (in this case x) in the console. So far I only found examples and help where the value is constantly printed, is is crucial for me however that it is printed only once.
In this sketch, I use keypresses instead of button press to troubleshoot the logic, in the end it would be perfect if i can apply a working logic with keypresses also to button presses.  Much thanks for any responses.

```
void setup (){}

void draw (){
   print();
 }

void print()

{

  if(keyPressed == true){
    int x = 1;
     println(x);
      x = 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's easier to deal with than it seems. I modified your code snippet to start you on the right track:

```
int x = 0;

void setup (){}

void draw (){
   print();
 }

void printX() {
  println(x++);
}

void keyPressed() {
  printX();
}
```

`keyPressed` is processed like an Event. It's fired only once every time a key is pressed, which is why I look for it in it's own event to avoid your problem.

The way you did it, you were looking if a key is being pressed for every iteration of the `draw()` loop. Of course, this loop will happen more than once while you press the keyboard key (by default 60 times, to be precise), hence the many iterations of the `println`.

I'll be around if you have any questions. Have fun!